# finer-grained control than with LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: shared-libraries, elf, ld-preload

I have a dynamically linked ELF executable on Linux, and I want to swap a function in a library it is linked against. With LD_PRELOAD I can, of course, supply a small library with a replacement for the function that I compile myself. However, what if in the replacement I want to call the original library function? For example, the function may be srand(), and I want to hijack it with my own seed choice but otherwise let srand() do whatever it normally does.

If I were linking to make said executable, I would use the wrap option of the linker but here I only have the compiled binary.

One trivial solution I see is to cut and paste the source code for the original library function into the replacement - but I want to handle the more general case when the source is unavailable. Or, I could hex edit the needed extra code into the binary but that is specific to the binary and also time consuming. Is something more elegant possible than either of these? Such as some magic with the loader?

(Apologies if I were not using the terminology precisely...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of wrapping malloc:

```
// LD_PRELOAD will cause the process to call this instead of malloc(3)
// report malloc(size) calls
void *malloc(size_t size)
    {
    // on first call, get a function pointer for malloc(3)
    static void *(*real_malloc)(size_t) = NULL;
    static int malloc_signal = 0;
    if(!real_malloc)
        {
        // real_malloc = (void *(*)(size_t))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        *(void **) (&real_malloc) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "malloc");
        }
    assert(real_malloc);
    if (malloc_signal == 0)
        {
        char *string = getenv("MW_MALLOC_SIGNAL");
        if (string != NULL)
            {
            malloc_signal = 1;
            }
        }

    // call malloc(3)
    void *retval = real_malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "MW! %f malloc size %zu, address %p\n", get_seconds(), size, retval);
    if (malloc_signal == 1)
        {
        send_signal(SIGUSR1);
        }
    return retval;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for answering with a great solution. By the way, while we are at it... is there also a way to edit the to-be-resolved symbol in the binary? E.g., if in the example above I could change "srand"  to something like "sran0", then a collision with an existing library would be super unlikely and I could then provide my own sran0 via LD_PRELOAD (which would then call the usual srand).

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is to use `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, ...)`.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html):

```
RTLD_NEXT
          Find the next occurrence of the desired symbol in the search
          order after the current object.  This allows one to provide a
          wrapper around a function in another shared object, so that,
          for example, the definition of a function in a preloaded
          shared object (see LD_PRELOAD in ld.so(8)) can find and invoke
          the "real" function provided in another shared object (or for
          that matter, the "next" definition of the function in cases
          where there are multiple layers of preloading).
```

See also [this article](https://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, regarding editing the function name in the binary - I checked and it works but not without potential hiccups. E.g., in the example I mentioned, one can find the offset of "srand" (e.g., via **strings -t x exefile | grep srand**) and hex edit the string to "sran0". But names of symbols may be overlapping (to save space), so if the code also calls rand(), then there is only one "srand" string in the binary for both. After the change the unresolved references will then be to sran0 and ran0. Not a showstopper, of course, but something to keep in mind. The dlsym() solution is certainly more flexible.